# How to specify cells' width in a table which contains input fields?

Tags: html, css

**A table with input field**:

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid orange;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 200px;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid orange;
  padding: .5em;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="width:70%"><label>Key</label></td>
    <td>Value</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="text">Key</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="text" value="Value"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**And a table without input field**:

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid orange;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 200px;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid orange;
  padding: .5em;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="width:70%"><label>Key</label></td>
    <td>Value</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="text">Key</label></td>
    <td>Value</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

So what is the right way to specify cells' width in this case? Really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATED[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8s0hs1kb/3/) . You can give the table `table-layout: fixed;` and then give to td whatever `width` you want. Also you should give to input type `width` 100%;

```
table{
    border: 1px solid black;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 200px;
}

input{
    width:100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Thank for your response! But the input field still breaks the cell padding.

Comment: @Dan9 That is because the input field has 2 px for its border so just give a width of 99% or 98% and it will be fine :)

Comment: Ah, it looks great now. Thank you!

Comment: Hey, look like we don't need `table-layout: fixed;`. We just need `box-sizing` and `width` attributes only. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [size Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_size.asp) of the `input` element

```
<td><input type="text" name="text" value="Value" size="20"></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td>sssss</td>
<td width="80px" style="border:1px solid red;"><input type="text" style="width:100px;"/></td>
  
</tr>
<tr>
<td>sssss</td>
<td style="border:1px solid green;" ><input type="text" ></td>
  
</tr>

</table>
```